# EC2 instance shuts down by itself

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, instance

EC2 Instance
Type: t2.micro
OS: Ubuntu 16.04.3
Config tool:Webmin

The instance has the "Instance State" as "running" but it is not really working. If I do right click -> "Instance State" -> "Stop" / "Start" then I can connect to the machine easily but after a while it goes again off.

When I try to connect I get

> This site can’t be reached
>   18.217.7.112 refused to connect.

after a Stop -> Start of the instance everything works again.

Can anyone help me troubleshoot this? Not sure where to look and what to look for.

Thank you!

Comment: Are you trying to ssh or access a web server hosted in the ec2?

Comment: How are you trying to 'connect' when you see that error?

Comment: I tried with SSH (Putty) - stays for a long time doing nothing, I tried to browse (Chrome) to the website or to Webmin console and I get that error

Comment: Did you create a rule that allows SSH from your IP address?

Comment: Do CloudWatch metrics indicate anything unusual on the instance, such as elevated CPU? It could be that the operating system isn't responding correctly.

Comment: @mnmopazem: SSH is allowed as I can connect after stop restart without any issues using Putty, but after a while I get the "refused to connect"

Comment: @John Rotenstein : If I look in the "Monitoring" tab of the EC2 Instance I see CPU only if I select "Last 3 hours", but if I select "Last hour" the CPU (and all other gauges) are completely blank. So it must have died out about 1-2 hours ago. This looks like the machine goes into a power saving mode or sleep or something... but I have no clue how to check or where this setting would be to turn it off.

Comment: after some more research I ran this:
sudo systemctl mask sleep.target suspend.target hibernate.target hybrid-sleep.target
I will let you know if it worked

Comment: nope, it did not work, it just shut down itself again

Comment: This is strange. Meanwhile, if you find a solution, do share same. Thanks and best wishes!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I found seems to have worked. I had another turn off, indeed, but maybe that was needed to take the new settings into account. So here is exactly what I did

- I issued the command 
  `$ sudo systemctl mask sleep.target suspend.target hibernate.target hybrid-sleep.target`
- My machine stopped again by itself even though in AWS it was showing "Running"
- then I did a right click and "Reset" from AWS screen

So my guess is that issuing the command and then reboot should do the job.
My machine is still up and running since Friday.